# Are ActiveX applets dead?

Tags: silverlight, activex

Are ActiveX applets as a technology supported by Microsoft dead?

What are the alternatives to ActiveX to create extremely rich internet applications using Microsoft Technologies? (Silverlight does not cut it for me, as it doesnt give me access to serial ports - or does it?)

Answer (score 10):

You can of course still make ActiveX applications, but know that they will only work with Internet Explorer, unless users of other browsers install hosting plugins, that aren't all that good anyway.

In either case, a web application that requires access to a serial port? Are you sure you're not better off with a desktop application instead? A simple refresh and you've cut off that serial port.

Not all applications belong in the browser.

Comment: To expand on this, you'd likely be much better off trying to add web functionality to a desktop app (post information to a web server), than you would being able to add desktop features like accessing serial ports to a web app.

Comment: The reason I have been looking at a web-app is that the only "desktop" type feature is the serial port access and access to a web-cam (which wont be accessible to all users of the system). Apart from that everything else, viewing/editing records, etc, feel natural in a WebApp.

Comment: "Not all applications belong in the browser" - exactly. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to launch an application via a web browser that can access the serial ports, one option would be to use Java Web Start with JavaFX as the rich interface API, and Java Communications for the serial port access. You could end up with a cross-platform application at the end as well.

Or just write a native application using your favoured Windows toolkit if you absolutely are restricted to using Microsoft tools.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveX as technology is very much alive, and will remain for many years to come. But its usage for Internet is dead. ActiveX is to be only used from within windows stand-alone applications.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX as of 2015 is a dead technology that even the maker is no longer interested in continuing to use it. Here is [something](https://mashable.com/2015/05/11/microsoft-edge-security/) to read.

Answer (score 0):

No, Silverlight is designed from the ground up to be completely sandboxed, no way to bypasss that (thank god).

If you need that kind of access, but are looking for an easy deployment, I would suggest building a Clickonce application.
There are restrictions, because I think by default they are not full trust, but that's the best you will get.
It's also going to be the only easy route if you need printing (unless you are willing to round-trip to a server to generate a PDF file).

If you need direct access to some hardware (like for a POS software with cash drawer, receipt printer etc), you need to go "desktop". Clickonce can give you some deployment options, XBAPs can give you the "browser experience", but you are going to have to make compromises based on what your "hardware access needs" are.

Comment: The only caveat I'd add is to say that Silverlight 3 and 4 have out-of-browser capabilities which don't remove the sandbox completely, but do extend it pretty significantly.

Comment: quite true, my answer was, at the time, in reference to Silverlight 2.
You might be able to do some things through the COM support added in SL 4, but then it's bye bye cross-platform support (if you need it)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I didn't notice the Silverlight exclusion in the original question.  My comment it not really applicable.  Sorry!

I don't know that I would call ActiveX dead just yet, but I would be cautious if you are planning to build an application based upon this technology.  My recommendation would be to use [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/).  This provides much of the functionality that is commonly desired in ActiveX controls, but uses the newer .NET technologies.

There is alot of talk about using Silverlight for media playback, but it has many powerful feature that can also be used to create Line-of-Business applications as well.  In fact there is a great podcast [episode on DotNetRocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=441) that discusses this exact subject.

Here are a few more links that might point you in the right direction:
[Microsoft Silverlight Getting Started](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/)
[Silverlight 2 and a Glimpse of Silverlight 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/16/update-on-silverlight-2-and-a-glimpse-of-silverlight-3.aspx) by Scott Guthrie

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Silverlight 4 still doesn't give you direct access to serial ports, but it *does* give you access to any local web cam and microphones now.  You could presumably also run Silverlight 4 out-of-browser, which gives you access to COM objects, and you could write a quick-and-dirty COM object which wrapped serial port access.  That said, I also agree with what folks said above about not all applications belonging in the browser.